# (Linux) Multi-User sequential server in c?

Tags: network-programming

I try to write a multi-user sequential server in  c(I think this is called round robin ). The server's behavior is like a cloud .Users give commands like upload and download,share,un-share.And finally, my question is...How can i process those commands sequentially in a non-blocking way? I mean, if clients A and B want to download a file from the server ,how can I gave them chunks of information in a non blocking, way until they have all the informations needed?could you give me some tutorials or useful documentation please?

Comment: What OS? e.g. in Linux sockets and forking child processes handles this nicely for you.

Comment: Linux but i want to do this without using fork .

Comment: This and it's sequel is very good, even though a bit old, article on Linux Network programming: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2333 . I recommend forking. It is great.

Comment: Thanks you very much !

Comment: Better add the link to the sequel here for completeness: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2335

Answer (score 0):

To make things non-blocking, you need to use `poll()` or `select()` system calls. Using these calls, you only read/write when needed, and hence the read/write calls will not block.